# Does pdf (or svg) support linear interpolation of colors inside a vector graphics triangle?

Tags: pdf, svg, colors, vector-graphics

We would like to blend colors specified at triangle vertices using linear interpolation (e.g. like OpenGL) in a vector graphics file like a pdf.

This example blends red, blue and green:

[image: linear interpolation of colors inside triangle]

Is this possible in PDF? If not, then SVG or some other well-supported vector graphics file-format?

It seems gradient meshes are powerful, but can they be degenerated to exactly reproduce linear interpolation?

Answer (score 1):

The pure answer to your question is "no".  You can't do three-point gradients in SVG or PDF.

However you can reproduce that image easily enough with a couple of gradients and a mask.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 86.6">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="bluegreen" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0.5" x2="1" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#0000ff"/>   
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00ff00"/>   
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="fader" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0.75" y2="0.5">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="redmask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M 0.5,0 L 1,1 0,1 Z" fill="url(#fader)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <g>
    <path d="M 50,0 L 100,86.6 0,86.6 Z" fill="url(#bluegreen)"/>
    <path d="M 50,0 L 100,86.6 0,86.6 Z" fill="#ff0000" mask="url(#redmask)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P48FD/

**Update:** Actually, what was I thinking? :/  You don't need a mask.  You can do it just with two linear gradients.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 86.6">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="bluegreen" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0.5" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#0000ff"/>   
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#00ff00"/>   
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="redfade" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0.75" y2="0.5">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ff0000" stop-opacity="0" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <g>
    <path d="M 50,0 L 100,86.6 0,86.6 Z" fill="url(#bluegreen)"/>
    <path d="M 50,0 L 100,86.6 0,86.6 Z" fill="url(#redfade)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3qjB/

Comment: I noticed that this doesn't appear correctly in Illustrator. Is this type of thing not compatible with PDF or other formats?

Comment: It's valid SVG, so if it is not appearing correctly in Illustrator, it must be because there are issues with its SVG import filter.

Comment: That's fair, but I imagine SVG isn't one-to-one with PDF. Can this be converted to a valid PDF?

Comment: I don't think the first version will convert cleanly to PDF because it uses masks. However the second version, I just added, will.

Comment: This answer is *almost* correct. Unfortunately it produces different results depending on the order of the three vertices. I think there is an issue with the alpha compositing.

Comment: What do you mean by "the order of the three vertices"?  If you move the vertices, you would need to move the coordinates of the gradients as well.  I didn't say it was a general solution for all possible triangles. Just that you *can* reproduce the effect if you are careful.

Comment: No, I mean if you do the linear gradients as redgreen bluefade instead of bluegreen redfade you get a different result on the same triangle.

Comment: It doesn't matter which corners the colours are in. It will still work. http://jsfiddle.net/DC67c/

Comment: Your new example also changes the position of the colors. Try switching between these two: your original http://jsfiddle.net/Q3qjB/ , same colors same positions different order (treatment in 2 gradients) http://jsfiddle.net/Q3qjB/1/ . They're close, but not the same and neither are the true linear interpolation.

Comment: I see what you mean now.  In theory, some combination of the color-rendering and color-interpolation properties should resolve that. However I am not sure if any of the browsers support them.